# Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a ThinkPad X1 Extreme won't turn off

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, thinkpad

I was trying to solve some problems with sound and BT on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 on a ThinkPad X1 Extreme laptop. After reinstalling the drivers I seem to get them back to work, but now the system doesn't turn off after I click the Power Off option. It does close the apps and something else, and then freezes at a screen with Lenovo and Ubuntu logos on a black background.

[image: red Lenovo and Ubuntu logos on black background]

The only way I can turn if off completely is to press the Reset button on the bottom of the laptop which disconnects the internal battery. How can I diagnose / fix it?